# QML bring child item to front

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to implement a way to bring a `ListView` in front of parent's siblings (in the case below: trying to get `list` to show above `field` items). When typing "show" on any item other than the last, I would like to see the `list` above all others. I know how QML's visual parent/child stack works, I just want to be able to somehow bypass that. I have tried changing the `z` value, but that wouldn't work as the parent/child relation takes precedence over layers. Here's what I'm trying to do.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

Window {
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 20

        model: ListModel {
            ListElement {
                text: "1"
            }
            ListElement {
                text: "2"
            }
            ListElement {
                text: "3"
            }
            ListElement {
                text: "4"
            }
            ListElement {
                text: "5"
            }
            ListElement {
                text: "6"
            }
        }
        delegate: Item {
            width: parent.width
            height: 40

            TextField {
                id: field
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.margins: 1
                text: model.modelData
            }
            z:2
            ListView {
                id: list
                anchors.top: field.bottom
                width: parent.width
                height: 200
                visible: field.text === "show"
                clip: true
                delegate: Text {
                    width: parent.width
                    height: 20
                    text: model.modelData
                }
                z:3

                model: ListModel {
                    ListElement {
                        text: "11"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        text: "11"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        text: "11"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        text: "11"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        text: "11"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        text: "11"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        text: "11"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        text: "11"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        text: "11"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        text: "11"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        text: "11"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        text: "11"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        text: "11"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        text: "11"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        text: "11"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        text: "11"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        text: "11"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        text: "11"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`z` values to be ignored as they don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to increase the z of the child ListView and the delegate of the main ListView:

```
Window {
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true
    ListModel{
        id: mymodel
        Component.onCompleted: {
            for(var i=1; i<7; i++){
                mymodel.append({"text": ""+i})
            }
        }
    }
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 20
        model: mymodel
        delegate: Item {
            QtObject{
                id: internal
                property bool isTop: field.text === "show"
            }
            width: parent.width
            height: 40
            z: internal.isTop ? 1: 0
            TextField {
                id: field
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.margins: 1
                text: model.modelData
            }
            ListView {
                id: childview
                anchors.top: field.bottom
                width: parent.width
                height: 200
                visible: internal.isTop
                z: visible ? 1: 0
                clip: true
                model: childmodel
                delegate: Text {
                    width: parent.width
                    height: 20
                    text: model.modelData
                }
                ListModel{
                    id:childmodel
                    Component.onCompleted: {
                        for(var i=1; i<10; i++){
                            childmodel.append({"text": "child"+i})
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, could you please explain the purpose of the `QtObject` here? I'm assuming it's just to hold the property without having a visual item.

Comment: @bardao It is always a good practice to make certain properties inaccessible, since this way we guarantee that the elements are used for what they were created, it is the same logic for the different types of access in C++: public, private and protected.